# Membership in ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, .net

Does anyone know how to use different provider for membership? Actually i want to use my own database for Membership in Asp.net.

Comment: You could have found plenty by googling... Just like [Membership and Roles - custom database.](http://forums.asp.net/t/1530495.aspx/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a video tutorial hooking up a custom SQL provider for membership:

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-create-a-custom-membership-provider

Answer (score 0):

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx) will tell you all about it.
Basically, you implement a class that inherits `MembershipProvider` and you change your provider in your web.config.
.NET doesn't care how you implement your provider as long as you implement the required methods of MemberShipProvider.